# Compilation error using both HashKey and RangeKey in dynamoDB with Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am using dynamDb with my springboot application. I am trying to save data in the table which has hashKey and sortKey. Initially I tried to annotate my HaskKey and sortKey with @DynamoDBHashKey and @DynamoDBRangeKey respectively. However this was giving me compilation issues. Upon search I found this article https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb/wiki/Use-Hash-Range-keys which explains how in springboot we need to create a composite key/id with annotation @id. This id will not be part of the table.
I implemented the same however I still get compilation error:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventRepository' defined in com.accuity.kyc.hep.repository.EventRepository defined in @EnableDynamoDBRepositories declared on DynamoDBConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/core/support/ReflectionEntityInformation\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)\r\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)\r\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290)\r\n\tat com.accuity.kyc.hep.HepApplication.main(HepApplication.java:16)\r\nCaused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'historyEventRepository' defined in com.accuity.kyc.hep.repository.HistoryEventRepository defined in @EnableDynamoDBRepositories declared on DynamoDBConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/core/support/ReflectionEntityInformation\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)\r\n\t... 19 common frames omitted\r\nCaused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/core/support/ReflectionEntityInformation\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)\r\n\tat java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)\r\n\tat org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBEntityMetadataSupport.getEntityInformation(DynamoDBEntityMetadataSupport.java:125)\r\n\tat org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.java:104)\r\n\tat org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.getDynamoDBRepository(DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.java:128)\r\n\tat org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.java:150)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:324)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:322)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:328)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)\r\n\t... 30 common frames omitted\r\nCaused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ReflectionEntityInformation\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)\r\n\t... 50 common frames omitted\r\n"}
```

My entity class looks like this:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Event")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Event {

    @Id
    private EventId eventId;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "id")
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    public String getId() {
        return eventId != null ? eventId.getId() : null;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        if (eventId == null) {
            eventId = new eventId();
        }
        eventId.setId(id);
    }

    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "eventDate")
    public Date getEventDate() {
        return eventId != null ? eventId.getEventDate() : null;
    }

    public void setEventDate(Date eventDate) {
        if (eventId == null) {
            eventId = new eventId();
        }
        eventId.setEventDate(eventDate);
    }
 
}
```

Composite key class:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EventId {

    private String id;
    private Date eventDate;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "eventDate")
    public Date getEventDate() {
        return eventDate;
    }

    public void setEventDate(Date eventDate) {
        this.eventDate = eventDate;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@EnableScan
@Repository
public interface EventRepository extends CrudRepository<Event, EventId> {

}
```

For dependency I am using:

id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.1'  and
com.github.derjust:spring-data-dynamodb:5.1.0

I have followed the similar example from couple of other sources. I can not see what am I missing.
Please help.

Comment: I'm looking at your error message dump.  It doesn't say much.  You cut it off though, adding `....` at the end.  It's possible that what came later in that dump would give more information.  Can you fix your message to supply the whole error message, and maybe format it so it comes out a bit more readable (ie: not all on one line)?

Comment: Updated the log section

Comment: can you put a reproducer to github ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue for this, https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb/issues/279. It appears the library is not compatible with Spring Boot 2.2. Per one of the commenters there is a fork available that may support this, but I haven't found this yet.

EDIT: The repository where this supposedly works now is at https://github.com/boostchicken/spring-data-dynamodb.